# How to change the storage location of VirtulaBox to other disk

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox

I am using ubuntu16.04. The hard disk partition in which the virtual box is stored is has no much empty space left.I am using windows 7 in the virtual box it has taken much space in which host os ubuntu is installed.So i want to change the location of of virtualbox to another partition in which there is much empty space is this possible?If possible how to change its storage location.

Answer (score 1):

If you Select from menu

```
File>Preferences...>General
```

you will find `Default Machine Folder`.

By choosing `other..` you can browse to any location.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

The `VirtualBox VMs` folder located at `/home/username/VirtualBox VMs` contains the virtual disk images, and takes the most room on your hard disk. It can be moved to another partition or disk. When you copy this folder to its new location, there's three things that need to happen.

## 1:

Change the `Default Machine Folder` in Virtualbox preferences...

[image]

## 2:

Move the original `VirtualBox VMs` folder to your desktop, to disassociate the virtual disk images from their previous location. Then check the `Virtual Media Manager` to assure that each disk image shows up properly at its new location. Re-assign its location if need be...
[image]

## 3:

Once you've proven that your guest OS's work properly, then delete the original `VirtualBox VMs` folder.